# Streaming video+audio from Pi4 to Pi4 via ethernet

Tags: pi-4, audio, streaming-video, ffmpeg, raspivid

I would like to stream video & audio from one Pi4 (equipped with mic/cam) to another Pi4 (equipped with screen/speaker) via ethernet (cable connected directly between them).

I've looked around, found a bunch of stuff about raspivid/ffmpeg, issues on older Pi models, but most don't bring in the audio and it doesn't seems to be easy to have it in sync with the video.

Any up-to-date info is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I can give precise details but if I recall correctly `pulseaudio` is quite happy to convey audio generated on one device on a LAN to another one.

IIRC you will want to use `paprefs` to enable the appropriate audio ends to be sent to/accessible from the network and if there is not a user logged into either device then you will need to configure `pulseaudio` to operate in "server" mode on that device.

For security you may also need to ensure they have the same "cookie" - if this has not been previously created (and it is required - not sure if that is optional) then a new random one will be generated - if the other end does not have the same one they will not connect to each other!